# Unable to download Rasterio python package

Tags: python, pip, package, rasterio

I am trying to download the `rasterio` python package for raster imagery and spatial analysis, but for some reason it just will not download for me, and I cannot figure out how to fix the error messages.

Here is what I have tried using anaconda prompt, with corresponding error messages:

Getting wheels from: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
and then running:

```
pip install rasterio-1.2.8-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

and getting the error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\MyName\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_87uij2u\\gdal_20c3e42f7deb4f0391b95ecaa08efa15\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_87uij2u\\gdal_20c3e42f7deb4f0391b95ecaa08efa15\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9h1v6979\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\MyName\anaconda3\Include\gdal' Check the logs for full command output.
```

and then trying to run:

```
conda install rasterio
```

and getting the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

and then trying to run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge rasterio
```

and getting the error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

and then trying to run:

```
conda create -n <MyNameEnv> python=3.7.4 rasterio
```

and getting the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment: / Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages. This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort. failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
Package python conflicts for: rasterio -> affine -> python[version='2.7.|3.5.|3.6.|3.4.|>=2.7,!=3.0.,!=3.1.,!=3.2.,!=3.3.,!=3.4.*|>=3|>=3.6|<4.0|3.7.*|3.8.*|3.9.*|>=2.7'] rasterio -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] python=3.7.4 Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

and then trying to run:

```
pip install rasterio
```

and receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\MyName\anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpse9bk5m1' cwd: C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-91t83nk4\rasterio_8716da7d81934830972987ae43921f13 Complete output (2 lines): INFO:root:Building on Windows requires extra options to setup.py to locate needed GDAL files. More information is available in the README. ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
```

I am not sure why none of these are working and am not sure what other options I have or what the root of this problem might be. How can I fix this so that I can properly download `rasterio` and use in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Until you solve this locally, you can install rasterio in Google Colab by running !pip3 install rasterio in an otherwise empty cell.

Comment: Did you actually read the last error message?

Comment: Since you are using Anaconda, [use conda to install rasterio](https://github.com/conda-forge/rasterio-feedstock#installing-rasterio)